# Why is my jQuery function not changing my class as requested?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my script, I run it at a certain point by echoing it in PHP:

```
echo "<script>$('.incorrect-guesses div:nth-child(2)').removeClass('empty-guess').addClass('incorrect-guess').text('2');</script>";
```

I'll eventually have it work for specific divs, but right now I want it to work for say the first (which is the second (:nth-child(2)) element of its parent), which it won't do. It's being applied to this HTML:

```
            <div class="incorrect-guesses">
                <h4>Incorrect Guesses</h4>
                <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
                        echo "<div class='empty-guess'></div>\n";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Each of the classes, `empty-guess` and `incorrect-guess` have specific properties. When I change it manually in my code it looks as it should, but this isn't changing the looks of the div when the user guesses wrong, which is what it should do.

Why exactly is this? I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: Please post an example with the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: when are you calling the script, which event triggers ?

Comment: I don't see any reason as to why you are trying to print the script through php? There is no variable that I see there. Plus as @Mooseman said in his answer, to bind your element with click event, you need to bind it after the element is loaded in DOM structure. And for that you need to wait until document is ready. If your script runs before the element is added to DOM it wont work.

Comment: code will only change class at run time... if you need it to do something based on user interaction you need to run it in an event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `$(document).ready(function(){` around your code:

```
echo "<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ $('.incorrect-guesses div:nth-child(2)').removeClass('empty-guess').addClass('incorrect-guess').text('2'); });</script>";
```

Also be sure that jQuery is being included on your page in the head.